# Software to test C# code

Tags: c#, automated-tests, code-analysis

Consider i have a C# code, I need some tool that would perform an analysis of my code and report bugs and vulnerabilities. Are there any open source tools, something like klocwork.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx) can perform static analysis of compiled assemblies, [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can analyze your program at source code level. Certain editions of Visual Studio have Code Analysis built into them.

As a sidenote: get up to speed on [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_test) (think [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) et al.)

Answer (score 2):

fxcop would be my first choice

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, write unit tests and use NUnit to run them. If you're looking for something like static analysis, you should use something like FxCop. You're not going to find a piece of software that will identify bugs automatically for you, but with unit testing and static analysis, you can get pretty close.

Comment: "You're not going to find a piece of software that will identify bugs automatically for you"; Actually, PEX *can* do this. Not all of them, but definitely some. See my reply...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there won't ever be a bit of software that can identify all bugs. Because you know, the halting problem and all. That looks like some interesting software, however.. I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I use Gendarme

Answer (score 1):

[PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) might be a good start - it will attempt to brute-force its way into every code branch; but ultimately, only you know what it is meant to do. You should be writing unit tests as you go, perhaps with [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) and [TestDriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/).

Answer (score 0):

FxCop is a static analysis framework available from Microsoft that works on Compiled Assemblies so it's good for any .Net Language

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx

If you're looking for strictly code analysis you may want to try Style Cop.  It's more for ensuring consistency though.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis

Answer (score 0):

In addition to FxCop already mentioned I'd add [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) to check if the code matches the coding guidelines. Next there'd be unit testing tools like NUnit or my personal favorite MbUnit or Pex and finally some tool to ensure you've handled all exceptions appropriately - again [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) or [Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm).